# mysql_affected_rows(); does not work for checking if row exists

Tags: php, mysql, sql, upsert

i am using mysql_affected_rows() to check if i  have to enter new record or update existing, but the problem is if the user tries to enter exactly same data as record which already exists it runs insert into.

```
$result = mysql_query("update Data set Score='$score',Comment='$_POST[Comments]' where Date='$_POST[forDay_3]-$_POST[forDay_1]-$_POST[forDay_2]' AND User='$_POST[UserID]';");
$last = mysql_affected_rows();

if ($last==0) {

    $result1 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO Data (User,Date,Score,Comment) VALUES ('$_POST[UserID]','$_POST[forDay_3]-$_POST[forDay_1]-$_POST[forDay_2]','$score','$_POST[Comments]')");
```

what should i do to avoid redundant entries

Comment: Please, please read about [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) immediately.

Comment: appreciate tht, but i am only trying to make the functional part first.

Comment: Just a suggestion, but I'd start looking into PDO. http://php.net/pdo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You could parse `mysql_info()` output (but the solution itself will be affected by race condition issue)
2. You could create unique key `User + Date` and end up with a single query using [ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) syntax:

   ```
   INSERT INTO `Data` (User,Date,Score,Comment)
   ('$_POST[UserID]','$_POST[forDay_3]-$_POST[forDay_1]-$_POST[forDay_2]','$score','$_POST[Comments]')
   ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Score='$score',Comment='$_POST[Comments]'
   ```

Comment: ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE method seemed easier and its working great!

Answer (score 0):

some solutions:

1. add another query to see if data exists, and then decide if you want to do some action (update/delete) or nothing.
2. add a 'modified' column with type "TIMESTAMP" and make it on update - CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

i'd go with first option.

btw, you should escape your post data (mysql_real_escape_string) to prevent injects or malformed query string

Comment: 1. It can cause race conditions, if OP will not take care of transactions and locks 2. There are systems where request can come within one second (thus will have the same timestamp)

Comment: 1. in php it should not cause problems. 2. use miliseconds then

Answer (score 0):

You may get the number of affected rows with `FOUND_ROWS()` instead of `mysql_affected_rows()`. The latter counts the not modified rows as well.

```
$result = mysql_query("update Data set Score='$score',Comment='$_POST[Comments]' where Date='$_POST[forDay_3]-$_POST[forDay_1]-$_POST[forDay_2]' AND User='$_POST[UserID]';");
$last = mysql_query("SELECT ROW_COUNT();");
$last = mysql_fetch_array($last);
...
```

Reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_row-count